# PHP DOM previousSibling doesn't work

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

```
<?php

$dom = new \domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
       <div>
        <h1>Title1</h1>
        <p><img src="" /></p>
        <h1>Title2</h1>
        <p><img src="" /></p>
        <h1>Title3</h1>
        <p><img src="" /></p>
        <h1>Title4</h1>
        <p><img src="" /></p>
        <p><img src="" /></p>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>');

        $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
        $nodelist = $xpath->query('//div/p/img');
        foreach($nodelist as $k=>$v){
            $title1 = $v->parentNode->previousSibling->textContent;
        }
```

I want to retrieve every text inside h1 tag, but previousSibling attribute seems to be not working, it returns a node without tagname attribute and its previousSibling attribute is "(object value omitted)"

My path must be followed as img->p->previous h1 , since not every p tag has its own h1 tag in my case.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your markup above, note that the immediate sibling of `<p>` is actually a new line character `\n`.

As an alternative, you could check for that preceding sibling first and check whether it's an `<h1>` tag, if it is, then get its `->nodeValue`:

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query('//div/p/img');
foreach($nodelist as $k=>$v) {
    // $previousSibling = $
    $prev = $xpath->evaluate('./preceding-sibling::*[1]', $v->parentNode);
    if($prev->length > 0 && $prev->item(0)->tagName === 'h1') {
        echo $prev->item(0)->nodeValue, '<br/>';
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9seY3O)

Comment: Thank you, to fully get what your code means I've gone through quite a lot of Xpath articles and find your solution is right. However, there's something I still can not understand. 1. I've tried remove './' and it works fine, is it necessary? 2. preceding-sibling::*[1] I changed it to preceding-sibling::h1[1] and if this is better? 3. Like my question stated I  don't know why PHP built-in property doesn't work. Anyway, thanks for your solution as it can solve my problem in another way, but I truely wanna go through my initial path to sort it out !

Comment: @user7031 it just gets the previous single element, after that it just checks if there is one and if its an `<h1>` tag, if it is, then get the text. glad this helped

Comment: It helps 99% of the part! Really nice, just trying to figure out how to solve it through the propery provided with PHP, if no one answers my question in a few hours I will mark yours as the accepted one! thank you!

Comment: @user7031 No, `./` is not necessary - and it's something you can always omit from XPath expressions (but `.//` has to be kept sometimes, and cannot be replaced with `//`).

Comment: Oh yes you are right, and My Sec Question, your solution is right !